# SSH RFC User authentication Message SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys, public-key

I'm working on some proprietary development on SSH protocol.

I want one clarification on message SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST

As per RFC 4252, client can send this below message to server to just verify the whether publickey would be acceptable or not.

byte SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST
string user name in ISO-10646 UTF-8 encoding [RFC3629]
string service name in US-ASCII
string "publickey"
boolean FALSE
string public key algorithm name
string public key blob

Once above message is replied properly by server with SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK.

Then client sends actual authentication message described below.

byte SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST
string user name
string service name
string "publickey"
boolean TRUE
string public key algorithm name
string public key to be used for authentication
**string signature** :This extra than first message

Now I can see first message (without signature) contains publickey blob. 
Should I verify the blob in first message or I should always skip that and do verification only during actual authentication message ?

I'm asking this because I have implemented my code like it does verification on both messages. But whenever i'm trying test against OpenSSH, it fails on first message for authentication but always get passed with second message. However i have debugged and found out OpenSSH is not sending same publickey blob in both message. so my question is why OpenSSH is doing so ?

Is OpenSSH is properly following RFC then seems like i should skip verifying publickey blob in first message. if i do that , am i not breaking the RFC ? doing that is right or not ?

Please help me to resolve this query. 
Please let me know if more information is required. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Now I can see first message (without signature) contains publickey blob. 
> Should I verify the blob in first message or I should always skip that and
> do verification only during actual authentication message ?
```

It is not clear what you mean "verify" for the first message,
but, for that message, sshd will just check if the given publickey blob exists in **~/.ssh/authorized_keys** file.  If it exists in that file, ssh client will receive SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK .

```
> However i have debugged and found out OpenSSH is not sending same publickey
> blob in both message. so my question is why OpenSSH is doing so ?
```

I had implemented a ssh client in Java from scratch, but I had not recognized such OpenSSH behaviors.

Comment: I'm implementing SSH server and I have observed OpenSSH client behavior. I think you have tested your client with OpenSSH server.

Comment: However i have checked OpenSSH code as well and I found, as OpenSSH server they don't check publickey blob in first message. They are only verify second message publickey. :)

Comment: What do you mean 'check public-key blob in first message'?  What kind of check or verification you have tried without a signature?

Comment: Refer to send_pubkey_test() and sign_and_send_pubkey() in sshconnect2.c of OpenSSH. It is unbelievable for me that OpenSSH client will do such a behavior.

Comment: """What do you mean 'check public-key blob in first message'? What kind of check or verification you have tried without a signature? – ymnk """""
 
In my server, I keep hash generated after key is installed so instead of checking big length key, i check hash. and I'm trying to compare hash of received key and installed key when i receive first message. But OpenSSH client send different publickey blob so this check fails.

Comment: i have already referred send_pubkey_test and sign_and_send_pubkey. Main concern is even RFC is not much clear. It says first message is only for verifying whether publickey method would be acceptable or not? and publickey field in that may contain "certificates?. It's says it may so it's not compulsory that other party should verify that so seems like OpenSSH is ignoring check on server side code and not sending actual key in client side code. I think now i feel like OpenSSH implementation is as per RFC only. What's your opinion ?